# Detect if a swf is running in an Android application's web view?

Tags: android, flash

Is it possible to detect, from within Flash, if the currently-running swf is executing from within a [web view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) embedded within an Android application?

Answer (score 0):

this is easily accomplished by checking the user agent of the browser .
i goggled it for you and found a topic about it .. lol i guess you just needed to know the the browser has a user agent  .
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-detect-the-browser-and-user-agent-with-as3/

Comment: I believe the User Agent received is the same as if the swf was loaded in the Android's browser; that it is not different if loaded in a browser vs. loaded in a Web View. Can you confirm that it is different?